# How to force a salt state with onchanges based on a state in the 'include' section

Tags: yaml, jinja2, salt-stack

I want to restart a service (haproxy) on a machine based on changes executed on another state. This would tipically be easy with `onchanges` but I have a particular case. Here's the state:

```yaml
include:
  - linux.v1_0

(...)

ftp.service:
  service.running:
    - reload: True
    - watch:
      - <what to use here?>
```

I've seen people saying to use the watch in order to restart. Thing is, the `linux.v1_0` state included will make some changes and I want to restart the haproxy service only anf if changes are actually applied by the state. I would like to avoid to explicitly use `systemctl restart haproxy`.

The linux.v1_0 state has the following:

```yaml
{% set ssl = pillar.get("c") %}


{% for domain, cert in ssl.items() %}

cert.ssl.crt.{{ domain }}:
  file.managed:
    - name: etc/ssl/{{ domain }}
    (... more stuff ...)

{% endfor %}
```

So the task ID itself can vary from various domains, for example `cert.ssl.crt.pt` or `cert.ssl.crt.es`.

On the original state, I want the ftp service to restart ONLY when there are changes on the `cert.ssl.crt.{{ domain }}`task on the linux.v1_0 state.

Comment: to answer this we would need to know the states within linux.v1_0 as what goes in watch would be a state within that state.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the description. I hope it helps, thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, Salt requisites work on state ID. It does not matter whether a particular state ID is in found in `include`d SLS or in-line. This can be checked with `state.show_sls`.

With respect to the dynamic state IDs getting generated, we can use the `_in` variant of the `watch` requisite, i.e. `watch_in`.

Like so:

```
{% for domain, cert in ssl.items() %}
cert.ssl.crt.{{ domain }}:
  file.managed:
    - name: etc/ssl/{{ domain }}
    (... more stuff ...)
    - watch_in:
        service: ftp.service
{% endfor %}
```

While it will work for this requirement, any other SLS that includes `linux.v1_0` will have to define `ftp.service:`. Please try to keep `linux.v1_0` self-sufficient with related service restarts/reloads if possible.